# A duplicate compiled file is created every time I compile C++ program with same name as "a.exe"

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, sublimetext3, gnu

Whenever I am compiling any C++ file in sublime text editor build option (by pressing ctr+b and build system as C++ single file run), its generating same copy of the compiled file with name "a.exe". Hence whenever I hit the build option I get 2 .exe files. One that I actually intended to get and other exact copy of the file with "a.exe" name.
I am unable to open build settings to check if I accidentally added something in the build settings.
Please help

Comment: Sublime Text doesn't have built-in functionality to build programs. It merely executes a script or using a configuration that is used for the building. You need to figure out the configuration or script used to see what it does and how it's configured.

Comment: Do you know how to find and edit the same?

Comment: When you choose `Tools > Build With...`, what option do you pick in order to build your program?

Comment: C++ single file - Run